# Why does variable assignment work like this in lists?

Tags: python, variables

```
a = [0]
b = a
a[0] = 1

print b
```

this will print 1, why does this work for lists but not for int's or float's or anything like that?

Comment: `b` is a reference to `a`. Can you give an example how you would do this for ints or floats?

Comment: Because ints and floats don't support `a[0] = 1`, or anything else that would mutate the int or float.

Comment: `print b` does not print 1, it prints `[1]`

Answer (score 3):

```
a = [0]    # create an int, create a container referencing the int, let "a" reference the container

b = a      # let "b" reference the same container as "a"
a[0] = 1   # create another int, let container "a" reference the new int

print b    # "b" and "a" refer to the same container with the new contents
```

See this [Python Tutor visualization](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=a%20%3D%20%5B0%5D%0Ab%20%3D%20a%0Aa%5B0%5D%20%3D%201%0A%0Aprint%20b&cumulative=false&curInstr=4&heapPrimitives=true&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=2&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false) for a clearer picture of what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

All types in Python are reference types. <strike>The trick is that some are mutable and some are not. `int`s and `float`s are immutable. The value 42 can't be changed. Every time you assign a new value to a variable, it's pointing to a new value.</strike>

`a` and `b` both refer to the same array in your code. That's why, when you modify the array using one identifier, you see that change reflected when accessing the value using the other identifier.

Comment: Sorry, but mutability has nothing to do with it.  Even if the OP's "0" and "1" were replaced with lists like ``[]`` and ``[[]]``, the effect would still be present.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger - You're right. Struck it out. My sleep deprived mind was trying to go somewhere with it and it made no sense.

Comment: No worries.  It happens to the best :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one if you are having problem with copying a list

```
>>> a = [0]
>>> b = a[:]
>>> a[0] = 1
>>> a
[1]
>>> b
[0]
```